# Sum $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!k!} = ? $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to evaluate the following sum

$$   \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!k!} = ? $$

Is there an exact evaluation ?

asymptotics?

Comment: you already wrote the exact evaluation didn't you?

Comment: Which begs the question: what do you call "to evaluate"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum is:
$$I_0(2\sqrt x)$$
It can be derived remembering that:
$$I_\nu(z)=\frac{1}{2}z^\nu\frac{(\frac{1}{4}z^2)^k}{k!\Gamma(\nu+k+1)}$$
where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of zero order of the first kind.
$\Gamma$ is the Gamma function: $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$

Comment: this is more a comment. And for someone who doesn't know the modified besselfunction of first kind this isn't really helpful at all

Comment: This is not an answer. Please explain more.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: despite this, the modified Bessel function of the second kind is the correct answer, I think.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: I agree with Riccardo, although his characterization of which Bessel function is described is incorrect (it is the modified Bessel function of the first kind).  Upon correction and maybe some elaboration (perhaps pointing out the differential equation solved by this Bessel function and its Taylor series), this is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @RonGordon: I corrected the mistake. It's a modified Bessel function of the first kind

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: I think you may wish to elaborate on the answer a bit.  What is $I_0(0,z)$ vs $I_0(z)$ and why does it equal to the posted sum?

Comment: The Maple command $$sum(x^k/(factorial(k)*factorial(k)), k = 0 .. infinity); $$ produces $${\rm BesselI}\left(0,\,2\,\sqrt {x}\right). $$ See [BesselI](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Bessel) for info.

Comment: Unless it had been mentioned before, to write $\,I_0\;,\;\Gamma\;,\;I_\nu\;$ etc. without even saying what are these cannot be considered an answer or anything close to it.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I suppose, a person writing here asking a question concerning calculus, should be able to understand the answer. Otherwise he should read what he needs to understand the answer. I can't explain what is a Bessel function, where it comes from, what is a series and so on.

Comment: Not at all, @Riccardo.Alestra . First, the tag is "sequences and series", which is usually taught in 1-2-nd year calculus and it's pretty far away from Bessel/Gamma functions and stuff, so the OP may have never even heard of that. Second, *even* if we assume knowledge, **mentioning** by name our symbols makes crystal clear what we mean, and I mean symbols which may be non-standard or advanced and thus not usual for all. I, for one, know the Bessel functions of the 1st kind by $\,J_n\;$ , and the one of the second kind by $\;Y_a\;$, none of which you used...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Ok. I completed the answer.

Comment: Nice to see, @Riccardo.Alestra . I think the answer may well be beyond the OP's knowledge so far, yet it is complete now. +1

Comment: Dear all, good work. +1

Comment: Do we consider that it would **hurt** the OP to ask for explanations about an answer if they find they do not fully understand it, say, for problems with the notations? If not, what is the fuss about?

Comment: How do you analyze series of the form $$\sum_n \alpha_n I_n(x)$$ ?? In particular I have a series of the form $$\sum_n y^n I_n(x)$$ with $y\in\mathbb{R^+}$